# Why are most KeyGen algorithms constructed to be probabilistic algorithms?

Tags: randomness

Are deterministic keygen algorithms unsafe? Why?

Comment: Are you asking about deterministic algorithm with no secret random input, as in the two current answers? Or deterministic algorithms fed a secret random input? The later kind is not uncommon, and can be safe if the random input really is secret.

Comment: @.CHG: Introducing Attribute Based Encryption in the question after 3 answers are given (as in revisions 2/[3](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/109634/3)/4) is unfortunate, for it invalidates the three existing answers. I have thus reverted these changes. I suggest you accept the most useful answer, and ask a new question. **Update** The new question asking this for ABE was posted [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/109665/555).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of key generation is to construct a key that your adversaries can't figure out. If your adversaries can figure out your key, then they can decrypt your secret data, or forge signatures, or do whatever the key is for. Cryptography aims to protect against adversaries who aren't stupid, so you can't hope to be more clever than them. The only way that you can find a key that your adversaries can't is if you know something they don't.

Sometimes you can construct a key from another secret key, deterministically. This is called [key derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (or sometimes “deterministic key generation”, but that terminology is confusing since “key generation” normally refers to a randomized process). A common scenario where this happens is when establishing a communication channel: first the two parties use a [key exchange or key establishment method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) to figure out a shared secret, then they use the same key derivation on both side to construct communication keys.

But in many scenarios, you don't have another secret key. How can you know something that your adversaries don't, if you don't already know something they don't? One thing they don't know is the output of your random generator: that's what a cryptographic random generator is for. The definition of a random generator in cryptography is that it gives outputs that nobody else can guess. Thus a key generation process uses the output of a random generator to construct a key. For symmetric keys, this is typically a trivial process: read $n$ random bits, use them as an $n$-bit key. For asymmetric cryptography, this is typically a more complex process because the key has to have some mathematical structure. The details depend on the cryptosystem.

Every key generation process can be turned into a deterministic process by using a fixed sequence of bits whenever the key generation process calls a random generator. For security, the sequence of bits must be indistinguishable from a random sequence, so it's often the output of a cryptographically secure pseudorandom generator, seeded with a secret key. Conversely, every key derivation process can be turned into a randomized process if you use the output of a random generator as the “secret” input.

Comment: [Mandatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a *fully* deterministic keygen algorithm in python for AES. Would you use this? I certainly wouldn't!

```
def keygen():
    return b"YELLOW SUBMARINE"
```

With that said, keygen algorithms are sometimes defined as deterministic processes of a random seed. For example, a keygen uses a key derivation function on an input seed to derive the seed. But again, the overall security of the scheme will still depend on having a good random seed.
In conclusion, a secure keygen may be seen as a deterministic or probabilistic function depending on your abstraction boundary. But there must be some randomness "somewhere" lest you want to find yourself singing *"We all live in a yellow submarine..."* with the NSA and GCHQ.

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic key generation algorithm implies that there exists only a single possible key. Which is equivalent to having no key at all.