# Why are most ABE KeyGen algorithms probabilistic algorithms?

Tags: randomness, key-generation, abe

It seems that in most Attribute Based Encryption schemes, the keygen algorithm is probabilistic, which means that given the same public key, master secret key and attribute set (or access structure), it may output different secret keys.

Is my opinion correct? If correct, why is this? Will a deterministic keygen algorithm affect the security of an ABE scheme?

Comment: Can you link one that is not probabilistic?

Comment: @kelalaka Do you mean present an ABE scheme that has a deterministic keygen? Actually, I haven't found one.

Comment: So. simply the answer to your previous question is valid for almost all cases..

Comment: OK, but why IPFE scheme can have deterministic keygen? [Here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/209.pdf) is the example.